# Simple vending machine with one drink in python

Tags: python

I'm nearly finishing this project but still get an error saying my code doesn't accept invalid inputs, for example...if I input a string instead of an integer throws an error instead of accepting and show a message.

This is the error i get...

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
:( coke rejects invalid amount of cents
    Did not find "50" in "Amount Due: 20..."
```

the code:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    while True:
        total += int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").strip())
        coke = 50
        print(total)
        if total > coke:
            print("Change Owed =", total - coke)
            return
        elif total == coke:
            print("No Change Owed, Here's a coke ")
            return
        else:
            print("Amount Due =", coke-total)


main()
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is more code that goes with this? Where does ```:( coke rejects invalid amount of cents``` come from for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say you input a string, do you mean like "20" with quotation marks?

if so put .replace('"','').replace("'","") next to .strip() will sort that out to get rid of " and ' .

```
total += int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").strip().replace('"','').replace("'",""))
```

Comment: This answer has already been given

Answer (score 1):

If you can't fulfill the requirement because your code should accept invalid inputs, for example letters, and not crash, you could try the following with a try-expect-block

```
def main():
    total = 0
    while True:
        try:
            total += int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").strip())
        except ValueError:
            print("The input is not a number, please only enter numbers")
        else:
            coke = 50
            print(total)
            if total > coke:
                print("Change Owed =", total - coke)
                return
            elif total == coke:
                print("No Change Owed, Here's a coke ")
                return
            else:
                print("Amount Due =", coke-total)


main()
```

For more information about using exception i would suggest you to read the [Python-documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove any excess `'` and `"` from your string input.
This can be done with the `.replace` method:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    while True:
        total += int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").replace('"', '').replace("'", '').strip())
        coke = 50
        print(total)
        if total > coke:
            print("Change Owed =", total - coke)
            return
        elif total == coke:
            print("No Change Owed, Here's a coke ")
            return
        else:
            print("Amount Due =", coke-total)


main()
```

Comment: It accepts strings if they are given like ```'20'``` or ```"20"```?

Answer (score 0):

Try-Except would be a way out, but as we didn't see it yet in cs50p week 2, i suspect we should find an answer without using it.
The thing your code is missing is a validation to check if the input is a 5, 10 or 25 cent coin. You can do that with:

```
if input in [5, 10, 25]:
```